# How to map the macOS Clear key to NumLock with iTerm2?

Tags: macos, iterm, keybindings

I tried, but failed, mapping macOS <kbd>Clear</kbd>  key to <kbd>Numlock</kbd> functionality in latest **iTerm2** (Build 3.4.23) on macOS Sonoma.

I did not see any relevant setting in **iTerm2** Preference dialogs:

- iTerm2 *Preferences/Profiles/Terminal* and *Preferences/Profiles/Keys* (General and Key Mappings) do not seem to offer that ability, but macOS Terminal.app does.

With macOS Terminal.app it can be done by adding the <kbd>Clear</kbd> (Keypad) to <kbd>Numlock</kbd> key map in Terminal Profiles/keyboard.  I have been doing it for a while as I use that in Emacs running in a shell under Terminal.app.  It gives me control over the behavior of most numeric keypad keys to activate extra functionality with the <kbd>Numlock</kbd> is off.
I would like to do the same with Emacs running under iTerm2.

Does iTerm2 Preferences offer a setting to control the mapping of the <kbd>Clear</kbd> key?

Comment: For anyone interested about what I do with it in Emacs running under Terminal.app, I document it in my PEL project on GitHub at: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pierre-rouleau/pel/master/doc/pdf/numkeypad.pdf